# Function in JS that return defined data with 1 second delay

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, task

So,i have a task,to make a function '*mocker*' which will return defined data with 1 second delay.The problem is that i'm new in JavaScript world and idk how to do this.I tried to take this way:

```
mocker = function mocker(data) {
    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        return data;
    }, delayInMilliseconds);};
```

But it doesnt satisfy the assignment.
I have this example :

```
 const getUsers = mocker([{id: 1, name: 'User1'}]);
getUsers().then((users) => { // Will fire after 1 second.
  console.log(users); // result: [{id: 1, name: 'User1'}];
});
```

And this is function description for test :

```
describe('mocker', () => {
describe('users mocker', () => {
    const usersData = [{id: 1, login: 'mickey'}, {id: 2, login: 'billy77'}, {id: 3, login: 'coooool123'}];
    let getUsers;

    beforeEach(() => {
        getUsers = mocker(usersData);
    });

    it('should return users data', async () => {
        const resultData = await getUsers();
        assert.deepStrictEqual(resultData, usersData);
    });

    it('should return users data in asynchronous way', () => {
        const resultData = getUsers();
        assert.notDeepStrictEqual(resultData, usersData);
    });
});
```

});

```
@param data: {Array | Object}
@returns {Function}
```

Can you guys please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test suggests it's a little more complicated than just creating a function that returns some data after a second.

This line:

```
getUsers = mocker(usersData);
```

is saying that `mocker` needs to 1) accept some data and 2) return a function that we assign to `getUsers`. When we call `getUsers` it will then call that function to return the promise of data.

So when we get here:

```
const resultData = await getUsers();
```

we're calling that function we assigned to `getUsers` that promises to return some data (or not) after a second.

```js
const usersData = [{id: 1, login: 'mickey'}, {id: 2, login: 'billy77'}, {id: 3, login: 'coooool123'}];

// `mocker` accepts some data and returns a
// function. This function is assigned to `getData`, and
// when `getData` is called this is the function that gets executed.
// It returns a promise that after one second data will be returned.
function mocker(usersData) {
  return function () {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => res(usersData), 1000);
    });
  }
}

// So we call `mocker` and assign the function it
// returns to `getUsers`
const getUsers = mocker(usersData);

async function main() {

  // We can then call `getUsers` to get the data
  // after one second has passed
  console.log(await getUsers());
}

main();
```

Additional documentation

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: Woah ! I'd never do this,it seems easy and hard in the same time.. I had some examples with promises but there were used for API and i could not put that knowledge into this implementation. Thank you so much !

Comment: I'm not sure why they're using [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) here because you could just pass in the data to `getData`, but they are an important concept in JS, and that's probably what they're testing.

Comment: Yes,thats why i couldnt do it,in task description was written something, but in test was completely different